# if statement is blocking the socket from emiting messages to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I've come across something very strange with my code. I have a function that updates the chat room using sockets. Everything was working perfectly until I got the number of clients in the room.

```
function updateChatRoom(user, gender, vip, firstname, message, latitude, longitude, room, updateUser)
    {
        const messageDetails =
        {
            gender: gender,
            vip: vip,
            firstname: firstname,
            content: message
        }

        /*********** IF I DELETE THIS IF STATMENT, IT SENDS TO THE USER ********/
        if (user.in('/').adapter.rooms[room].length)
        {
            messageDetails.roomLength = user.in('/').adapter.rooms[room].length;
        }
        /*********** IF I DELETE THIS IF STATMENT, IT SENDS TO THE USER ********/

        if (latitude && longitude && typeof latitude == 'number' && typeof longitude == 'number')
        {
            messageDetails.latitude = latitude;
            messageDetails.longitude = longitude;
        }

        if (updateUser)
        {
            console.log("sending to user"); //Always runs, regardless if the if statment is there or not
            user.emit('incomingChatMessage', messageDetails); //I only receive this if i delete that if statment
        }
        user.in(room).broadcast.emit('incomingChatMessage', messageDetails); //Always runs
    }
```

So if you can see that if statement in the middle. That gets the amount of people in this room. From testing and debugging, I can see that it's correct. However, when its there, the user.emit doesn't run, or if it does, it doesn't send anything to the user.

I know that updateUser is true too because it always logs 'Sending to user' to the console.

If I simply delete the if statement, it sends normally. My only guess is that when I'm checking the room length, I'm changing a property of the user so it doesn't get sent to them anymore? I have absolutely no idea.

Also, the last line that emits the message of everyone in the room except the client, that works with or without the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `if` code into `try...catch` block, and print the exception to the console log. I think somewhere in your code you have and `try...catch` block, where `catch` is empty and do nothing.

Comment: I did, theres no error. It also prints the result out correctly everytime.

Comment: console log `messageDetails` before emiting

Comment: messageDetails logs as normal, just an object. Your second comment is what im thinking

Comment: i tried taking the if statement out and just putting 'let x = user.in('/');' which caused the same result. Maybe its opening up a new connecting or something

Comment: then try to avoid using this and find another way to get room length.